# Printooth is not printing the image

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I'm trying to print[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Imc2.png) a QR Image using [Printooth Library](https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth). but problem is that its not printing as expected.

this is code which i used to create a QR

```
try {
            qr = QRCode.from("www.example.org").to(ImageType.JPG).bitmap()
        } catch (e: WriterException) {
            Log.e("Error", "is ${e.message}")
        }
```

i checked the QR in imageview and it is fine. i'm using this code for the printooth

```
add(ImagePrintable.Builder(qr).setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.ALIGNMENT_RIGHT)
                .build())
```

[and result is in attach image](https://ibb.co/FxrYB4g). Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

so i found that i was not converting the my bitmap image to black and white which was important, and also it was printer issue.

```
 al.add(new ImagePrintable.Builder(toGrayscale(bitmap))
                .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getALIGNMENT_CENTER())
                .build());

 public static Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap srcImage) {

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcImage.getWidth(), 
    srcImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(srcImage, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```